# Imported packages not recognized by module function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter notebook I am working in. In the first cell, I import several common packages:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
```

In the next cell I import a package called "apt_pkg", which contains a module named "test_mod.py":

```
from apt_pkg import *
```

The module "test_mod.py" contains the following function:

```
def working():
   print('Is working')
   print(np.nan)
   return
```

Then I run the function in the Jupyter notebook:

```
test_mod.working()
```

When I do this, I get a NameError ("NameError: name 'np' is not defined"). The code can be seen here:

[screenshot from Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puW97.png)

If I change the function and reference matplotlib.pyplot as plt (e.g. plt.show()) or pandas as pd (e.g. pd.DataFrame), I also get a NameError where 'plt' or 'pd' is not defined. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `np` inside `test_mod.py`:

```py
import numpy as np

def working():
   print('Is working')
   print(np.nan)
   return
```

Importing `numpy as np` inside the Jupyter Notebook is not sufficient: you need to import the package in every script that needs it (here `test_mod.py`)